# How can I get Google Calendar events or system added calender events in Android?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I'm new in android and in my android project, I used google calendar. I used an add new event button in my activity layout and I use the android system calendar. However, when I want to see my events everytime, I need to open up the default Calendar app. How can I fetch events that I added using button on my app or see the events from system calender in my activity?

A snapshot of my current activity with just one button:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4zit.png

```
 Calendar cal;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_takvim);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nav_takvim, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.profil){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),navProfil.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.signOut){
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeNav.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_babycontroller) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),navBebekKontrol.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_calender) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),navTakvim.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_story) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),navMelodi.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    public void onAddEventClicked(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis()  + 60 * 60 * 1000;

        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime);
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,endTime);
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);

        intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Lütfen başlık giriniz");
        intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION,  "Etkinlik tanımı");
        intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Mekan ismi");
        intent.putExtra(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=YEARLY");

        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```